# Uncaught Error: Class 'PDO' not found in autoload/global

Tags: php, pdo

I am running a php app on AWS Server i upgraded to php 7.2 and since then its giving me this error.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'PDO' not found in /var/www/html/test/config/autoload/global.php:21 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/test/vendor/zendframework/zend-config/src/Factory.php(110): include() #1 /var/www/html/test/vendor/zendframework/zend-modulemanager/src/Listener/ConfigListener.php(363): Zend\Config\Factory::fromFile('/var/www/html/t...') #2 /var/www/html/test/vendor/zendframework/zend-modulemanager/src/Listener/ConfigListener.php(139): Zend\ModuleManager\Listener\ConfigListener->addConfigByPath('/var/www/html/t...', 'glob_path') #3 /var/www/html/test/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(322): Zend\ModuleManager\Listener\ConfigListener->onMergeConfig(Object(Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleEvent)) #4 /var/www/html/test/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(171): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners(Object(Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleEvent)) #5 /var/www/html/test/vendor/zendframework/zend-modulemanager/src/Listener/ConfigListener.php(165): Zend\EventManager\EventM in /var/www/html/test/config/autoload/global.php on line 21
```

my global config file is below

```
<?php

return array(
    'db' => array(
        'driver' => 'Pdo',
        'dsn' => 'XXXXXXX',
        'username' => 'XXXXX',
        'password' => "XXXXX",
        'driver_options' => array(
            \PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\', time_zone = "' . date('P') . '"'
        ),
    ),
);
```

Comment: enable PDO in php.ini

Comment: You might also need to install the `php-pdo` package. The base PHP package doesn't include many of the extensions by default.